# How to create a Google Analytics dashboard widget that reports the number of unique visitors that didn't have any event?

Tags: google-analytics, widgets

I have a dashboard on which I want two widgets:

- **Widget one**: A *statistics* widget with the count of *unique visitors* that did **not** fire *any event actions*.
- **Widget two**: A *statistics* widget with the count of *unique visitors* that did fire *specific event actions*.

Widget two was a piece of cake:

- Statistics: `Unique visitors`
- Filter: Only show `Event action`, with regular expression: `(action1|action2|action3)`

But I can't seem to get widget one to work, I tried the same setup as two but as regex: `.+` and exclude instead of only show. This would seem to me like it would exclude all unique visitors with any event action? Instead it shows results in 0 visitors.

**Edit**: Oh, and it is important that the widget actually exclude **any** event action, not just the action1, action2 and action3 from the other widget.

Comment: Does the regex work with `include` to show you a subset of your visitors, or with an include does it show you *all* your visitors?